# Filter a column based on a list of words in R

Tags: r, string, filter, dplyr

I would like to filter a column in a dataset with >2 million rows. The filtering should be done if any of the rows in that column contain words from a list of 70 words.

I used this `fruits$type[grepl(c("apple","orange","grapes"),fruits$type)]`
But I get error as below:

> argument 'pattern' has length > 1 and only the first element will be
>   used
>   It works fine when I just use one word to filter but I have around 70 words, hence it will be difficult to individually write 70 lines.

I tried suggestion mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22850026/filtering-row-which-contains-a-certain-string-using-dplyr) but not working.
Could anyone please help me?

Comment: I think you need to use `grepl("apple|orange|grapes", fruits$type)`

Comment: I tried that earlier as well, it gives this error "operations are possible only for numeric, logical or complex types"

Comment: No idea, have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5680819/subset-a-data-frame-in-r-using-or-when-the-column-contains-a-factor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are many key words, we can loop through the words do the `grepl` and with `Reduce` and `|` get a single logical vector to subset the dataset

```
res <- fruits$type[Reduce(`|`, lapply(v1, grepl, x = fruits$type))]
length(res)
#[1] 11
```

#### data

```
v1 <- c("apple", "orange", "grapes")
set.seed(24)
fruits <- data.frame(type = sample(c("apple", "orange", "grapes", 
    "banana", "water melon"), 20, replace=TRUE), val = rnorm(20), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Comment: thanks it pulls up those rows. Perhaps I wasn't clear in my question. How can I select all the other columns associated with this result? Perhaps pipe it in dplyr?

Comment: @Tony In that case, you don't need to select that column. i.e. `fruits[Reduce(`|`, lapply(v1, grepl, x = fruits$type)),]`